# Find 2d data points which fall within certain area

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I have a large set of data which represents coordinates on a two dimensional plane. What would be an effective and efficient method to find all of the x,y pairs that fall within a variable radius based around a variable point? (Any tips for storing the data that would make processing it easier is also very welcome)

**EDIT**

Final application is being written in Javascript, specifically Node.

**EDIT**

I've found that a rectangular area is also allowable rather than a radius, the borders of the rectangle would still be variable however. A I've stated in a comment below, I should specify that the final data set will have millions of entries and traversing the entire set for each request is not feasible.

Comment: Do you know the point to search around before hand? Are you allowed to use a database that supports spatial queries?

Comment: Is the radius always going to be the same size for each query? If not how much does it vary by? This will affect the choice of spatial data structure that is most efficient for your purpose.

Comment: It's just a raw table of data currently. I am open to suggestions for storing it, but it does need to be stored locally and accessible through a Node.js app. The point being searched around will vary, but will obviously be known each time. The radius will also be variable.

Comment: How many points in total, how many points per query (typical) ? How are the points spread ?

Comment: My tests are only being conducted with about 50 points (to make it easier on me to debug in development), the final application will have milions of points. Efficiency is a significant concern and traversing the entire set for every request just isn't feasible.

Answer (score 1):

The point to point distance should be less than the radius of the circle being searched. To improve the search, one might also implement binary search or [kd-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).

```js
var getPoints = (function() {
  var points = [{
    x: 90,
    y: 70
  }, {
    x: 100,
    y: 80
  }, {
    x: 20,
    y: 40
  }]
  return function() {
    return points;
  }
})();

function dist(point1, point2) {
  var pow = Math.pow;
  return Math.sqrt(pow((point2.x - point1.x), 2) + pow((point2.y - point1.y), 2));
}

function drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, fill) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  if (fill) {
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fill();
  }
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  context.stroke();
}

function spatialSearch(centerX, centerY, radius) {
  var points = getPoints(),
    res = [],
    len,
    r = 5,
    fill,
    i;

  drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius);

  for (i = 0, len = points.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    ele = points[i];
    fill = undefined;
    if (dist({
      x: centerX,
      y: centerY
    }, ele) <= radius) {
      res.push(ele);
      fill = 'green';
    }
    drawCircle(ele.x, ele.y, r, fill);
  }
  return res;
}

spatialSearch(100, 75, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Comment: Due to the size of the data set, traversing the entire set for each query may be a problem. It's not 100% not an option, just 99.999%. The final data set will have millions of points and it needs to be able to satisfy multiple queries at a time, so evaluating each point may be too much.

Answer (score 0):

@Ayan's approach is very straighforward, but here are some other techniques to consider.  You're going to have to measure with your actual data to know what really works, though.

If you have a very large number of points, step one is to get rid of all points outside of a bounding box that contains your circle.  Let's say the circle is centered at (ox, oy) with a radius of r.  Then you can discard all points who's x value is outside of ox+/-r (and same for y value).  If your points are sorted by the x coordinate, you should be able to use a binary search to narrow it down on the x coordinate, and then do a linear scan on the remaining points candidates with a plausible y value.

Then, the most straightforward approach is to compare the square of the euclidian distance with r^2.  This avoids doing the square root in the standard distance formula that @Ayan is doing above, which is quite expensive.  So just calculate whether r^2 is less than (ox - px)^2 + (oy - py)^2.  Since the latter is just addition and multiplication, should be reasonably quick.

If you can accept some approximation, you might consider sampling the -y and +y of the circle along certain buckets on the circle, and storing those in a lookup table.  Then, for a given point (x, y), you look up the appropriate bucket for that x and see if y is in between the points you've precalculated.  You'd really have to have a lot of points for this to be faster though.

Comment: Keeping the points sorted by x and narrowing down from there may be an option. It is a very large set of points so I'm going to try it and see if I can implement it without too significant an impact on performance. I don't know for sure if it will work, I have points in the millions it has to be able to handle.

Comment: You might, as @Ayan suggested, use a k-d tree.  This structure is meant to do efficient range searches just like this.  There are at least three node packages that implement for you.  See https://github.com/mikolalysenko/static-kdtree, which has benchmarks against the other two.